# Adding numbers to cell references in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was asking myself whether it is possible to add numbers to cell references which are used for formulas in Excel.

In my case I have the formula

```
    =VAR.P('Excess Return'!E2:E22)
```

which obviously gives me the variance for the numbers ranging from E2 to E22.

Now I want to drag down the formula for all other cell and therefor i want something like

```
    =VAR.P('Excess Return'!E2:E22+D3)
```

with the number 4 in the Cell D3 for example.

Now Excel should do

```
   =VAR.P('Excess Return'!E2:E26)
```

but it doesn't and returns "#NAME?"

Any idea on how I can solve this problem?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

**EDIT for clarification**

My example wasn't really what I actually meant. Sorry for that.

So I have two columns with numbers E and F. In column G there is the formula.

```
    G2 = VAR.P('Excess Return'!"E"&E2:"E"&F2)
    E2 = 2
    F2 = 22
```

which then should result in

```
    G2 = =VAR.P('Excess Return'!E2:E22)
```

So I want to insert the numbers stored in column E and F into the cell reference for the variance function.

Comment: I edited the initial example to better reflect what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I suggest using `=VAR.P(INDEX('Excess Return'!E:E,E2):INDEX('Excess Return'!E:E,F2))`... it is not volatile and should be faster for bigger sheets ;)

Comment: Great, it works as intended! Many thanks Dirk Reichel!

Comment: Cool stuff @DirkReichel I didn't know INDEX() could return references, not only values.

Comment: @pnuts I simply "answered" my `INDEX`-solution on the other question... while it isn't something new, and also has a lot of limitations, you can use it to use full columns in array formulas like finding the longest string in column A would be something similar to `{=MIN(IF(LEN(A:A)=MAX(LEN(A:A)),ROW(A:A)))}`. Now to *not* go for the whole column, simply replace the `A:A` with `A1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("zzz",A:A))`to only use column A till the last string (and I am sure you have seen the last code-sniped already somewhere) ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If the size of your referenced range is not supposed to change while dragging down, you can probably do what you want by properly using [relative and absolute cell references](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Switch-between-relative-absolute-and-mixed-references-dfec08cd-ae65-4f56-839e-5f0d8d0baca9)
- If you want to change your reference based on the value of **another cell**, however, you probably need an [indirect reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261).

Solving your example with INDIRECT():

```
=VAR.P(INDIRECT("'Excess Return'!E"&E2&":E"&F2))
```

Another way to reference indirectly - **preferable** because it is less volatile and causes less recalculations:

```
=VAR.P(INDEX('Excess Return'!E:E,E2):INDEX('Excess Return'!E:E,F2))
```

Thanks @DirkReichel for pointing out that alternative.